How can I bring in the JSON string as a variable in a PySpark function?
The goal is to call a filter function from JSON as a string from an Excel document. The JSON will be updated in an Excel report and the goal is to pull in the filter and then makes sure the filter function makes sense with the given data. We also have the logic file which contains the match values and the ranges. I am really struggling and not sure where to start. Basically, I have a logic file, JSON String, and some data and I need to run the JSON on the data but also use the logic file to get the match and the year range.
My main question at this point is: How can I bring in the JSON string as a variable in a PySpark function? Would I create a data frame from the JSON? Or can I turn the JSON filter variables into SQL where clauses?
Any other advice in terms of the pipeline and steps I should take would be very much appreciated. Ultimately we need to not just filter the data but also have checks for things like new values in GSBER that were not in the previous logic/lookup table. I'm just feeling a little overwhelmed at this point.
Logic File
Sample Data
// use a logic table to filter a data table
// - Keys defined by type and column(s) in order, combined by AND
//      key[0] is match data."GSBER_BUSINESS_AREA" on logic."GSBER"
//      key[1] is determine if 
//                   data."GJAHR_FISCAL_YEAR" >= logic."FY range start"
//          AND data."GJAHR_FISCAL_YEAR" <= logic."FY range end"    
// - FilterAction = {"include" -> filter in,
//                           "EXCLUDE" -> filter out}
{
"process": "Filter", {
      "logicTableNm" : "WC/Lab-ERP"
      "logicKeyTp": {
              {"match","GSBER"},
              {"inRange", "FY range start", "FY range end"}

I tried to read in the JSON as a data frame but I'm not sure how to add these as variables in a function. I just don't understand how to work with JSON and I would like one example of how I can take JSON and turn into into variables I can use in databricks preferably in pyspark or spark SQL.

Hi, it would be awesome if you could show us what you have tried so that people have a bit more context and they can follow up on your approach. Also, it is often better to not use pictures for the data. Instead, add the tables in the question itself.

@Bruce Jenks can you share some sample data

You can convert the JSON to normal JSON and apply your filters in a UDF like below.
First, I took a sample input dataframe df which contains the JSON string column as below.



Id
myjson




1
[{"name":"Rakesh","age":23},{"name":"Luffy","age":19},{"name":"Shanks","age":38}]


2
[{"name":"Buggy","age":38},{"name":"Kick","age":12},{"name":"John","age":21}]



Here, for sample I am using UDF to apply a filter and get the names of the people who are older than 20 like below.
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType,ArrayType
import json

# A sample udf to get the names of the peoples who are older than 20
@udf(ArrayType(StringType()))
def operate_json(json_str):
    # read your logic file as a dataframe and apply your filter logic. 
    # You can convert this JSON object to a dataframe as well to apply your filter logic.
    l=[]
    json_obj = json.loads(json_str)
    for i in json_obj:
        if(i['age']>20):
            l.append(i['name'])
    return l

# calling udf on the JSON column and this generates new column with required filtered data
df2 = df.withColumn("req_names", operate_json(df["myjson"]))

# Show the DataFrame
df2.display()

This UDF converts the JSON string in each row to JSON object and stores in a variable. You can create your own logic based by checking on this JSON object or you can create a new dataframe out of this JSON. In this UDF, Read your logic file as a dataframe or SQL table and use that for filtering the JSON data and return the filtered data to your original dataframe as a new column. After returning you can select your required columns from that dataframe as per your requirement.
Sample Result:

